# Why does Mg(HCO₃)₂ on heating gives Mg(OH)₂?

Tags: solubility, precipitation, alkaline-earth-metals

Normally, bicarbonates on heating forms carbonates.
Why does Mg not give this too?

In a reference book I am referring to, it is given that it is due to high solubility  product of Mg(OH)₂ compared to Mg(CO₃) .

Then shouldn't the latter form? As even small amounts of it will lead to precipitation, driving the equilibrium  forward?

Edit: This is related to removing temporary hardness of water.

Comment: Wikipedia states that both magnesium carbonate and magnesium hydroxide decompose at 350 °C to yield magnesium oxide. So what temperature do you consider "heating" to be?

Comment: I suppose he means boiling water with bicarbonates. The provided argument does not make much sense to me, as calcium hydroxide has even higher solubility product than magnesium hydroxide.

Comment: The molecules get enough energy to efficiently collide with each other.All old bonds are broken atoms and electrons are reorganized and new bonds are created to replace the old ones.Try read Arrhenius theory of chemical reactions.